# log4net: creating one file per call

Tags: log4net

I have a server application that processes messages. We need to keep a separate log file for each message process. 
We have used Adam's answer to a relevant question:
[Logging to an individual log file for each individual thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7093864/3594348)

The only problem is that when the process is done, the repository needs to be disposed. We call

```
log4net.LogManager.ShutdownRepository(logFileName + "Repository");
```

when the process ends, but the LogManager still references the created repository. So, every call adds a new repository, thus causing increasing memory.

Is there a way to properly dispose the repository? Sorry for opening a new question, I don't have enough rep to comment on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The loggers defined in your repository are not really supposed to be cleaned up. However there is a way if the repository you are using is a [Hierarchy](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.html) (cast it to be sure); just call the [Clear](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.Clear.html) method.

A note of warning: only do this if you don't need the Repository anymore, the documentation warns that :

> This call will clear all logger definitions from the internal
>   hashtable. Invoking this method will irrevocably mess up the logger
>   hierarchy.
>
> You should **really** know what you are doing before invoking this method.

(emphasis not mine :) )

Comment: Calling [Shutdown](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.Shutdown.html) on Repository, clears the appenders. Calling [Clear](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.Clear.html) clears the loggers. But still the repository exists in the internal collection of LogManager, and the collection constantly increases.

Comment: Too bad, I thought this coul be sufficient for you needs. Then you have to create your own IRepositorySelector, and provide access to its Repository collection; there is no access to the Repository collection in the current selectors.