# How to log to separate log file per thread using log4net

Tags: .net, multithreading, logging, log4net

Yes this question is similar to:
[How to log into separate files per thread with Log4Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612317/how-to-log-into-separate-files-per-thread-with-log4net)
 except I don't know the number of threads or their names until runtime.  My windows app spawns a thread per user to do long running work for that user.  I want a separate log file for every user/thread.

1. What would the log4net config file look like (if one can be used for this type of thing)?
2. What would the code look like to use the logger?
3. When would I call `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()?`

(Please give details on how to implement the logging.)

Here's a sample config (I can't get the thread_name property to work with multiple threads):

```
<log4net debug="false">
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <!--need to replace LogDir in code like this:  log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogDir"] = "c:\programdata\myapp"-->
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogDir}\logs\mylogfile_%property{thread_name}.log" />
  ...
```

And the code:

```
public class MyMultiThreadedClassForUsers
{
    private log4net.ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public void Start()
    {
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties("LogDir") = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)        
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()

        List<IUser> users = GetAllUsersFromDB();

        foreach (IUser user in users) {
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(CallBackMethod);
            t.Name = user.FirstName;
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    private void CallBackMethod()
    {
        // this log message should be sent to a log file named after the current thread System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name
        // Examples: mylogfile_bob.log, and mylogfile_fred.log, etc...
        Log.Info("Starting work on thread " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        // do long running work here
    }
}
```

If this is not easily done with log4net I may switch logging frameworks to Nlog and use their %threadname keyword as part of the log file name which is stored in the config file.

Comment: Yes, it can very easily be done.  Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324053/configure-log4j-to-log-to-custom-file-at-runtime.  Just base the filename on threadid or some other guaranteed-unique tempname.

Comment: That doesn't work.  It keeps logging to the file specified in app.config.  Can you give me a working .net example?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

> http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/dynamic-log-filenames-with-log4net.aspx
>
> If you needed to generate dynamic logfile names with log4net then you
>   can use the following config
>
> ```
> <appender name="RollingFileAppenderV1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
>   <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="F:\HornetFeed\%property{LogName}" />
>   <appendToFile value="true" />
>   <rollingStyle value="Size" />
>   ...
>   <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
>     <Key value="Version" />
>     <StringToMatch value="1" />
>     ...
>     <= Note the "%property{LogName}" syntax
> ```
>
> Note the %property{LogName} this is a log4net Property which we can
>   set at runtime using C# code.
>
> ```
> log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "file1.log";
> ```
>
> Remember to set the GlobalContext Properties before instantiating the
>   log4net logger. i.e. before this call:
>
> ```
> log4net.ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
>   ///Helper method to log errors:
>   internal static void LogError(Exception ex)
>   {
>     string state = "1";
>     if (log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Version"] != null)
>       state = log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Version"].ToString();
>     log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Version"] = "0";
>     logger.HandleException(ex, "Error");
>     log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Version"] = state;
>   }
> ```

'Hope that helps

Comment: That doesn't work either :)  I know how to dynamically set the name of a single log file using GlobalContext.Properties, but I need to dynamically assign a different log file to every thread.  I'm not sure what the filtering is doing, but I tried it and it didn't do anything.