# How to log GStreamer messages to a file

Tags: python, c, gstreamer, glib

I have a video processing daemon (python), which runs several  processes, some of which use GStreamer to get raw video frames to my custom elements (C). Some of the processes "freezes" (Process `is_alive() = True`, but Gstreamer pipeline doesn't do anything and doesn't call any python callbacks) - usually after 2-10 days, and only in production. I was unable to replicate this on my computer.

Now I have log files from python logging (main program) and glib logging (C plugin), but there is nothing helpful, even after I've added a lot more logging messages everywhere. So I hope there would be some clue in GStreamer's messages.

I run glib "main loop" in processes dedicated to video processing and then send messages with results using `multiprocessing.Queue` for further processing to another process.
These gst/video-processes are a bit alien to python - there are a lot of callbacks from gstreamer and other gstreamer weirdnesses. Thats why I've isolated them in separate processes.

I have some python logging in the callbacks and a lot of glib logging in C plugin, but It's clearly not enough. Something probably fails between python program and C element. So I really need to see what's going on in GStreamer's guts.

Unfortunately, it seems to me that there is no way to debug Gstreamer other than by intercepting `stderr`.

I've tried to run the program without daemonization, set `GST_DEBUG` and store `stderr` into a gzipped file, but it doesn't help much, because I get all GStreamer messages mixed up in one **HUGE** file.

### To sum this up:

- I have a daemon (therefore no stderr, no stdout)
- In the daemon, I have many child processes
- Some of them (14 of them actually) run GStreamer pipelines
- I have some mystery failures
- I need GStreamer debug output badly
- But I need GStreamer messages from each process written to a different file so I won't get lost in them
- I don't know how to do this.

---

As suggested in comments, I could use `GST_DEBUG_FILE` env.variable, but that works from GStreamer 0.10.31. I have 0.10.30 so I can't use it.
Or I could write custom log handler, but since it would have to be written in python and `gst_debug_log_default' is not accesible from python bindings, this won't work either (maybe I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have write your own log handler.
Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429692/gst-debug-how-to-save-logs-in-a-separate-file-for-a-thread-inside-an-applicatio) question and its answer. Please see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the `GST_DEBUG_FILE` environment variable was what I was looking for - it's surprisingly hard to find in any GStreamer documentation - unfortunately, it seems that it is not supported in my GStreamer version (0.10). As for writing custom handler - I'd have to write it in python, and that seems to be impossible (no python binding for `gst_debug_log_default`) :(

Comment: Documentation says that `GST_DEBUG_FILE` is supported from version 0.10.31. I have 0.10.30.

Comment: Well even if it doesn't help me as much as I've hoped for, it IS the only viable solution.